# How to swap adjacent bytes in a string of hex bytes (with or without regular expressions)

Tags: python, regex, string, hex

Given the string (or any length string with an even-number of word pairs):
"12345678"

How would I swap adjacent "words"?

The result I want is
"34127856"

As well as, when that's done I need to swap the longs.
The result I want is:
"78563412"

Comment: if the string is "123456789012"  , what should be the output?

Answer (score 5):

A regex approach:

```
import re
twopairs = re.compile(r'(..)(..)')
stringwithswappedwords = twopairs.sub(r'\2\1', basestring)
twoquads = re.compile(r'(....)(....)')
stringwithswappedlongs = twoquads.sub(r'\2\1', stringwithswappedwords)
```

**Edit**:
However, this is definitely not the fastest approach in Python -- here's how one finds out about such things: first, write all "competing" approaches into a module, here I'm calling it `'swa.py'`...:

```
import re

twopairs = re.compile(r'(..)(..)')
twoquads = re.compile(r'(....)(....)')

def withre(basestring, twopairs=twopairs, twoquads=twoquads):
  stringwithswappedwords = twopairs.sub(r'\2\1', basestring)
  return twoquads.sub(r'\2\1', stringwithswappedwords)

def withoutre(basestring):
  asalist = list(basestring)
  asalist.reverse()
  for i in range(0, len(asalist), 2):
    asalist[i+1], asalist[i] = asalist[i], asalist[i+1]
  return ''.join(asalist)

s = '12345678'
print withre(s)
print withoutre(s)
```

Note that I set `s` and try out the two approaches for a fast sanity check that they're actually computing the same result -- good practice, in general, for this kind of "head to head performance races"!

Then, at the shell prompt, you use `timeit`, as follows:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s'import swa' 'swa.withre(swa.s)'
78563412
78563412
10000 loops, best of 3: 42.2 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s'import swa' 'swa.withoutre(swa.s)'
78563412
78563412
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.84 usec per loop
```

...and you find that in this case the RE-less approach is about 4 times faster, a worthwhile optimization.  Once you have such a "measurement harness" in place, it's also easy to experiment with further alternative and tweaks for further optimization, if there is any need for "really blazing speed" in this operation, of course.

**Edit**: for example, here's an even faster approach (add to the same `swa.py`, with a final line of `print faster(s)` of course;-):

```
def faster(basestring):
  asal = [basestring[i:i+2]
          for i in range(0, len(basestring), 2)]
  asal.reverse()
  return ''.join(asal)
```

This gives:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s'import swa' 'swa.faster(swa.s)'
78563412
78563412
78563412
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.58 usec per loop
```

About 5.6 microseconds, down from about 9.8 for the simplest RE-less approach, is another possibly-worthwhile micro-optimization.

And so on, of course -- there's an old folk (pseudo)theorem that says that any program can be made at least one byte shorter and at least one nanosecond faster...;-)

**Edit**: and to "prove" the pseudotheorem, here's a completely different approach (replace the end of `swa.py`)...:

```
import array
def witharray(basestring):
  a2 = array.array('H', basestring)
  a2.reverse()
  return a2.tostring()

s = '12345678'
# print withre(s)
# print withoutre(s)
print faster(s)
print witharray(s)
```

This gives:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s'import swa' 'swa.witharray(swa.s)'
78563412
78563412
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.01 usec per loop
```

for a further possible-worthy speedup.

Comment: Well done Alex. Once a programmer breaks out of the hall of mirrors that is regular expressions, they can do great things... Personally I want all my software to be over seven times quicker than my competitors!

Comment: @cudamaru, the latest version is 14 times faster than what I got with REs, and over 3 times faster what I first got without them. Being _hypnotized_ by REs' convenience to the point of not considering alternatives would be surely damaging. However don't neglect the possibility that (in other cases) the speed advantages might be exactly the other way 'round -- always consider and try various sensible possibilities when speed really matters!-)

Comment: Outstanding work there. More ammunition for my anti-RE campaign ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
import re
re.sub(r'(..)(..)', r'\2\1', '12345678')
re.sub(r'(....)(....)', r'\2\1', '34127856')
```

Answer (score 1):

just for the string "12345678"

```
from textwrap import wrap
s="12345678"
t=wrap(s,len(s)/2)
a,b=wrap(t[0],len(t[0])/2)
c,d=wrap(t[1],len(t[1])/2)
a,b=b,a
c,d=d,c
print a+b+c+d
```

you can make it to a generic function to do variable length string.

output

```
$ ./python.py
34127856
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub("(..)(..)","\\2\\1","12345678")
'34127856'
>>> re.sub("(....)(....)","\\2\\1","34127856")
'78563412'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do **endianness conversion**, use Python's [struct module](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) on the original binary data.

If that is not your goal, here's a simple sample code to rearrange one 8 character string:

```
def wordpairswapper(s):
    return s[6:8] + s[4:6] + s[2:4] + s[0:2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following approach:

```
data = "deadbeef"
if len(data) == 4: #2 bytes, 4 characters
   value = socket.ntohs(int(data, 16))
elif len(data) >= 8:
   value = socket.ntohl(int(data, 16))
else:
   value = int(data, 16)
```

works for me!